# sudden failure to boot 18.04

Tags: boot

A Successful upgrade to 18.04 from 17.10 and a few days of use.

Today i was working and 'black triangles' appeared on the screen. I decided to reboot to clear this.
However it failed to reboot! I looked at the log and the only relevant message seems to be :
failure to mount /proc/bus/usb
Can you advise please?
How can i recover the system?

Comment: Sounds like you might have a HW failure.

Comment: does machine boot off from ubuntu liveCD or its memory stick equivalent ?    to create that go to a working computer download ubuntu ISO then install ISO onto a memory stick using unetbootin then boot from it ... this will isolate whether issue is HW related or not